# Turn a manually program start to automatically program start on boot

Tags: services

I have installed osrm on my server in `home/myname/osrm`
if I manually start the process from beyond dir with `osrm-routed data/map.osrm` it works fine, but unfortunately in foreground and after reboot if have to start it manually again.
I tried to install it as a service

```
[Unit]
Description = starts up the osrm service
After = network.target
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/christian/osrm/
User=christian
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/osrm-routed   osrm-routed data/map.osrm
[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

But when I start the service I get always error messages like this

```
 [/etc/systemd/system/osrmstart.service:7] Executable path specifies a directory, ignoring: /usr/local/bin/osrm-routed/ osrm-routed data/map.osrm
Sep 01 14:03:46 ubuntu systemd[1]: osrmstart.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

What are I am doing wrong. I am very new to Ubuntu.

---

Thank you for answering to my question:

when i run:

```
file /usr/local/bin/osrm-routed
```

i get the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/osrm-routed: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=767f57fe712d25f03f1b2d18fd541d0253cd86d4, not stripped
```

i changed my osrmstart.service to:

```
[Unit]
Description = starts up the osrm service
After = network.target
[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/christian/osrm/
User=christian
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/osrm-routed   osrm-routed data/map.osrm
[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Now, if i first disable, then enable the `osrmstart.service` and then start the service with  `sudo systemctl start osrmstart.service`:
I get no error - but the service is not starting and is not available.

Manually i can start the process when i navigate to my home dir
~/home/osrm
and then typing `osrm-routed data/map.osrm` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
this starts the process - the process is a server, waiting on localhost:port5000 for queries like

```
http://192.168.1.200:5000/route/v1/driving/11.57787,48.13877;11.52045,48.13969?steps=true&alternatives=true&
geometries=geojson
```

and returns the way from target to destination,but manually the process is running in forground.

I need the service running in background, also when rebooting the system.
Maybe its only a type error - but i tried so many kinds of typings.
Maybe my answer helps a bit more, for helping me. Thanks in advance.

Christian

Comment: Like I said your code has syntax errors, please check the links I gave!

Comment: Now run `which osrm-routed` I suppose you will get `/usr/local/bin/osrm-routed` hence that will be the command to use in the `systemd` service file. And please remove the unnecessary spaces in your code!

Answer (score 2):

I see several issues here:

1. Code syntax errors your code should look like this:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=starts up the osrm service
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   Type=daemon
   WorkingDirectory=/home/christian/osrm/
   User=christian
   ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/osrm-routed data/map.osrm

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
2. `/usr/local/bin/osrm-routed` appears to be a directory not an `executable` file.

   - Run `file /usr/local/bin/osrm-routed` to determine for sure but I think you can know that by merely changing into it.
3. Note: Don't know what type of program your trying to run so `Type` option could be `Type=[simple|daemon|oneshot|forking|notify|idle]`

More information:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files